# How to access to properties of an object in kendo ui

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm not familiar with kendo ui, but I'm trying to make my code work.

I need to access to the properties of an object, check if the name of each property match a specified pattern, then assign a value to some variables according to the value of the property.

This is the code I produced:

```
#var propertiesKeys = Object.keys(properties);#
#var madreIdx, padreIdx, coniugeIdx, vedovanzaIdx, exConiugeIdx, conviventeIdx;# 


#for (var i = 0; i < propertiesKeys.length; i++) {#
    #var propertyName = propertiesKeys[i];#
    #if (/^\d+TipoParentela$/.test(propertyName)) {#
        <!-- Assign values to variables based on conditions -->
        #if (properties[propertyName].value == "GenitoreAnpr") {#
            # var genitoreIdx = i.toString();#
            #if (properties[genitoreIdx + "Sesso"] && properties[genitoreIdx + "Sesso"] == "M") { padreIdx = i.toString(); }#
            #if (properties[genitoreIdx + "Sesso"] && properties[genitoreIdx + "Sesso"] == "F") { madreIdx = i.toString(); }#
        #} else if (properties[propertyName].value == "ConiugeAnpr") {#
            #coniugeIdx = i.toString();#
        #} else if (properties[propertyName].value == "VedovanzaAnpr") {#
            #vedovanzaIdx = i.toString();#
        #} else if (properties[propertyName].value == "ExConiugeAnpr") {#
            #exConiugeIdx = i.toString();#
        #} else if (properties[propertyName].value == "ConviventeAnpr") {#
            #conviventeIdx = i.toString();#
        #}#
    #}#
#}#
```

The first line of code I provided `var propertiesKeys = Object.keys(properties);`is inherited from JavaScript and I suppose it will not work, but I don't know how to fix it.

How can I modify my code to make it works as I want?

Answer (score 0):

That code is within a kendo template, I can tell by all the #'s. A template is rendered against an object and within the template that object is the variable 'data' which is what I think you are after.

Try this as your first line:

```
#console.log(data)#
```

Then check the console output in the browser tools to see what properties 'data' has.